# Is there any spring hibernate annotations based java web cms

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, content-management-system

Is there any java cms for websites which uses spring hibernate annotation , which can make building sites easy.

Like user registration from with fields , login with spring security and some basic functioanlity.

Actually i am not sure what product i want but i will tell you the bsic requirement.

I am looking for something where i can select e.g registration form fields , login with spring security , user can edit those fields as weel .
forgot password thing , confirm email address  and a model all java spring files are created automatically and from there i can add my new features.

Because these things are basic in every web application and there has to be easy method to generate those things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Magnolia CRM](http://www.magnolia-cms.com/) ([Magnolia Community wiki](http://wiki.magnolia-cms.com/display/WIKI/Home)) has a module called [Blossom](http://wiki.magnolia-cms.com/display/WIKI/Magnolia+Blossom) that provides Spring integration for Magnolia. (That works for Spring 3 too)

Magnolia store its Content in [Java Content Repository](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_repository_API_for_Java) and not in a Data Base. That works very well for the cms content, because Mangolia provides a good Api for accessing it.

If you have your own business domain model and want to store it in a Data Base, you can add your JPA / Hibernate functionality like you do in "normal" Spring applications. (or like Sean Patrick Floyd suggested: invoke an other layer/server via for example Web Service).

*I have running such a System (Magnolia, Blossom, Magnolis JCR, Spring 3, Hibernate) with a small domain model stored "outside" of Magnolia in a seperate Database, and it worked very well. (But at the moment I am thinking of integrate the Domain Database in the JCR, not because of technical problems, but to reduce the amount used technologies/systems.)*

Anyway: Magnolia, Blossom, Magnolis JCR, Spring 3, Hibernate is worth to have a look at.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there should be one. Persistence Layer and Web Layer are two separate concerns, and it would be smelly to tie one to the other. The standard way to connect those two is through a service layer, and that is usually where the application's most important logic is. A CMS could simply not provide an abstraction that makes a service layer unnecessary without seriously restricting your application.

That said: [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/roo) goes in the right direction, it automatically creates Web Controllers from your entity classes. I'd say that's probably the best you can hope for.

Comment: Can i create pojo from database tables using roo